# I want to capture a video using jQuery webcam plugin

Tags: jquery, flash, webcam

I want to capture live webcam in the form of video, i am not getin the proper example in the official page documentation of the webcam plugin.How to do so???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the perfect plugin i wanted
[Opentok api](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api)

Answer (score 2):

Plugin which allows jQuery to read data from a user's webcam or other video capture device http://plugins.jquery.com/project/webcam

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the link u shared is displyaing the access denied page....:(